# TradingView Order Size : Contract in MT4|5 Lot

Tags: pine-script

Since I can't use my TradingView strategy with my broker, I will use Pine Connector to trigger my trades.

Since MT4|5 doesn't work with contract but with lot, I am struggling to find out how many lots is equals TV 1000 XAUUSD contract.

Help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I executed pinescript backtest with xauusd 100 contracts, and it shows the 130$ profit for 130pip movement.
  (1pip = 1point in xauusd, because it has two digits after point).
- And in MT4, with 1 lot, every 1pip price movement makes 1$ profit.
  (0.1lot, 1pip move makes 0.1$ profit
  0.01 lot, 1pip move makes 0.01$ profit
  etc)

From the two facts, **MT4 1lot = pinescript 100 contracts**.
You can make clear insights by observing profit per price movement.
Ignore other confusing materials that say different answer, and make your own decision.